# How to access a shared_ptr's data using find()

Tags: c++, reference, segmentation-fault, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have a pointer of shared_ptr map. I would like to find a particular element in the map, and extract it. I wonder how to find out if there is an element I'm looking for, and how to get to that element if exists. I was able to get this much, but I am not sure about -- the questions in comments :)

Apologies in advance, I am a c++ novice and I'm trying to learn as I code to achieve what I wanna see...

price_manual.h

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<ExtendedPrice>>> ExtendedPriceMapPtr;

class PriceManual : public Manual 
{
    public:
        PriceManual(const std::shared_ptr<Action> action_p, ExtendedPriceMapPtr extendedPriceMap_p);
        void print();
    private:
        ExtendedPriceMapPtr d_extendedPriceMap_p;
}
```

price_manual.cpp

```
PriceManual::PriceManual(const std::shared_ptr<Action> action_p, ExtendedPriceMapPtr extendedPriceMap_p) 
: Manual(action_p),
  d_extendedPriceMap_p(extendedPriceMap_p)

void ExtendedPriceMap::print(const Something& something) 
{
    if (d_extendedPriceMap_p->find("name") != d_extendedPriceMap_p->end())
    // Is this a correct way of finding an element and making sure it exists?
    {
    // I would like to do something like
    // std::shared_ptr<ExtendedPrice> ext_price_p = d_extendedPriceMap_p["name"];
    // const ExtendedPrice extended_price = ext_price_p->extended_price();
    // to eventually get that extended_price.
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting a valid object after 'extended_price_map[some_key]'?

Comment: Is it `const Price& abc = extended_price->();` or `const Price abc = extended_price->price()`? You've used both interchangably in this question.

Comment: I could swear I have seen something similar just recently: [SO: A simple line of code is causing “Segmentation fault (core dumped)”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64364052/7478597). You should close/delete at least one of the questions.

Comment: @user3152801 oh my god... I think that's what it is! I have updated my code, and I'm having another problem haha I updated the question! thanks!

Comment: @NathanPierson Hi Nathan! Thanks for taking a look, I was actually trying everything I can think of to figure out why the segfault, and that's how it happened. My bad. I actually now think it's probably due to the map lookup that failed x.x I changed my code and the question even... I'm so lost...

Comment: @Scheff Hi! Yes! I fixed that problem (or I'm just running into another problem)! :)

Comment: find() should help you to do map lookup. What is the question now?

Comment: @BuildSucceeded if I do ```d_extendedPriceMap_p->find("name")``` it seems to be returning bool, not the object. How can I get the actual object out of that map of shared_ptr?

Comment: It do not return bool. it returns iterator to an element with key equivalent to key. If no such element is found, past-the-end (see end()) iterator is returned.Reference : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find

Comment: Hi @BuildSucceeded thank you so much for responding and your kindly explaining. I did look into more documents on cppreference and was able to get it working the why I wanted. :))